# Broken JSON generated by JsonBuilder.toPrettyString()

Tags: json, groovy

This generates valid json:

```
new JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toString()
```

This generates invalid json (fails to escape properly):

```
new JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toPrettyString()
```

The output I get when I run new `JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toPrettyString()` from within my environment (a handler from within a rather-large play-1.2.6 app): {\n    "test": """\n} which is not valid json.

When I run the script Opal wrote from the command-line I get valid JSON ("\"" instead of """), so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. I use Windows 7 64-bit (JDK 1.7.0_u67, groovy 2.3.6 installer), but the issue was encountered on our AWS machines which are all linux

**NOTE:** This is caused by using an old version of groovy (1.8.6) and has been fixed as of 2.3.6. I can't upgrade because it's a dependency of Play 1.2.6.

Comment: Could you show us the results and the parser you are using to come this conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both outputs are valid:

```
import groovy.json.*

def j1 = new JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toString()
def j2 = new JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toPrettyString()

println j1
println j2

def p1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(j1)
def p2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(j2)

assert p1 == p2
```

Comment: Strange, you're totally right, yet when I added those lines to run from within the infrastructure I'm getting something else (no escaping on inner double-quote character). I'll try to replicate that outside the environment I'm using. thanks!

Comment: Indeed, seems strange. Please accept the answer I You liked it.

Comment: The output I get when I run `new JsonBuilder([test:'"']).toPrettyString()` from within my environment (a handler from within a rather-large play-1.2.6 app): `{
    "test": """
}` which is not valid json

Comment: What version of groovy You have? What OS? I suppose it might not be reproductible.

Comment: When I run the script you wrote from the command-line I get the same result you got, so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. I use Windows 7 64-bit (JDK 1.7.0_u67, groovy 2.3.6 installer), but the issue was encountered on our AWS machines which are all linux

Comment: I'm using: `Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.8.0_05 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`. Check the details on the AWS instance.

Comment: Not sure how that'll help: I don't understand how my local environment produces two different results. My guess is that it's related to the fact the Play project has a ton of dependencies and if they satisfy groovy's dependencies then it'll end up using different code depending on whether it's the only dependency or not. I don't know how dependencies work in java - how strongly is groovy tied to the specific modules it was compiled against?

Comment: It's rather strongly tied. Are You using maven or gradle? Check the dependencies and You'll see If You have any conflicting versions.

Comment: Okay, I found the issue: The version of Play we're using (1.2.6) is bundled with Groovy 1.8.6 which displays the issue. It's been fixed in the mean time, probably.

Comment: Glad You found the solution.